# Is datetime-local removed from HTML 5.1?

Tags: html5

HTML5 seemingly introduces these two input types:

- [datetime](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/datetime) (with a timezone)
- [datetime-local](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/datetime-local) (without a timezone)

Even though both are present on the W3C wiki, the HTML 5.1 nightly draft recommendation [only mentions the datetime type](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#date-and-time-state-%28type=datetime%29), I can't seem to find any mention of `datetime-local`.

Has this type been removed (or renamed) from the recommendation, or can we still expect future support for it?

Comment: Also note this [related question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21263515/993547).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `datetime-local` state is part of:

- WHATWG’s [**HTML** (Living Standard)](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#local-date-and-time-state-%28type=datetime-local%29) (as of 2014-03-14)
- W3C’s [**HTML5 (Candidate Recommendation)** from 2014-02-04](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/forms.html#local-date-and-time-state-%28type=datetime-local%29)
- W3C’s [**HTML 5.1 (Working Draft)** from 2014-02-04](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html51-20140204/forms.html#local-date-and-time-state-%28type=datetime-local%29)

But it’s [*not* anymore in the **HTML 5.1 (Editor’s Draft)** from 2014-03-17](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#states-of-the-type-attribute).

It was [removed in a commit from 2014-02-11](https://github.com/w3c/html/commit/3e5df1ee1aebed37571a23c9b62adc74a92a04b9):

> Removing the definition of input type="datetime-local" and its sections
>   and references.

---

This was proposed in the mail [<input type=datetime-local> HTML5 CR bugs](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2014Jan/0072.html) from 2014-01-14.

Here is the thread where the removal got discussed in reply: [RE: <input type=datetime-local> HTML5 CR bugs [I18N-ACTION-279]](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2014Feb/0003.html)

> Our concern is, indeed, that “datetime-local” falsely implies local wall time (and thus a time zone). Developers are not good at identifying floating times as it is.
>   […]
>   I would add that floating timestamps (date *and* time are significant) are the least common case. Usually at that point you want to compute a local time value using time zone information. Generally, the use of floating time requires some forethought by developers to keep from getting into trouble. I could support removing datetime-local as a result. If it’s kept, I think I18N would prefer it to be renamed to include the word “floating” instead of the misleading “local”.

It seems that it won’t be removed from WHATWG’s *HTML* (at least for now). As this might lead to divergences, the topic [may be discussed](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/wg/2014-04-Agenda#Potential_Topics) on the next HTML WG meeting.

Comment: HTML 5.2 Editors draft now includes both `datetime` and `datetime-local`: http://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-type